# Shortning the path of Sql Database file

Tags: c#, sql, file, path

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Samples\MyApp\C#\bin\Debug\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

`E:\Samples\MyApp\C#\bin\Debug\Login.mdf`

Here Login.mdf is my database name, if i move this database to my different path, i need to change the address of login, Is there anyway that i can put it in bin folder, Only

```
AttachDbFilename=\Login.mdf;
```

i tried this but it does not works...
is there any ways?

Comment: Add mdf file to root of your solution. Set Copy output property to true than AttachDbFilename=\Login.mdf; should work.

Comment: Try to use `Application.StartupPath` and add it to connection if we are talking about win application.

Comment: example? please i din't get u

Comment: `@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" + Application.StartupPath +"\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"`